# Is there a solution for On-the-fly-encryption with active directory rules & policies?

Tags: encryption, databases, server, active-directory

I am looking at having our servers' sql databases for a few program and documents to be always encrypted on the HDD, but available to AD users.  So one or multiple users with the right AD privileges would be able to use those databases or documents on demand.  While anyone trying to view the files and/or not having privileges would not be able to view those.

Comment: What issue are you running into?  Is it that you don't know how to configure group policies for AD users for network drives?

Comment: No, I understand how to setup AD, and network drive permissions, but I am just uncertain about having the disk encrypted for someone else while there are user utilizing it. For example, if using veracrypt, would another user be able to see it while decrypted without password?

Comment: I believe that the AD policies will block access to the drive completely before any data can be read.

Comment: That does not really help.  I need a solution that keeps the HDD encrypted and integrates with AD policies.